# Midpoint Adjustment on Complimentary BJT Amplifier

Tags: guitar-amplifier

Looking at this whoknowswhat 100w amplifier on eBay.  There are two trim pots, one is for bias current, and the other for "midpoint" adjustment.   The schematic supplied does not show the pots.  I am wondering where they might go.  I had an all tube amp once that had a pot to eliminate DC to prevent magnetizing the OT and improved sound quality.  Would this be what they are talking about, except in the solid state realm we call it DC on the output?
Any comment welcome.[image]

Comment: Interesting--it looks like they've made an op amp out of discrete components. Odd way to go about doing things, if you ask me, though it would work. Probably not the lowest distortion, though. That's all unrelated to your question, though--I just find it interesting how they did that.

Comment: VR1 (above Q1 & Q2) and VR3 (above Q8). The numbering implies there's a VR2 somewhere ...

Comment: @brhans:  Thanks for the spotting. Unbelievable I did not see those.  The seller indicated there are only two trim pots.  As a rule, the schematics for eBay amplifiers are notoriously inaccurate as published.  They probably had a third pot at some iteration then trashed it.

Comment: @Hearth This is pretty typical of audio power amps today, pretty much a big discrete op-amp. The circuits in Doug Self's popular audio amplifier book are based on this concept. Distortion can be pretty low,

Comment: Drives me absolutely nuts when people draw "ground" symbols upside down!!!!

Comment: @Kyle B: Yes, most annoying, as is skipping component numbers.  I had too quickly given up on the trim-pot location search because the convention of the "ratchet and pawl" symbol was expected.  Those over there don't sweat, in their mind, are insignificant or unnecessary details.  I missed them in ignorance because I always thought they were only required for pairs of transistors; to balance them instead of matching.  I have not yet considered how in the case of one set they will prevent thermal runaway, except that I really don't need that to happen.

Comment: Actually skipping component numbers is "the right thing to do"... When you delete a component during schematic development, you aren't supposed to re-use the designator.  Avoids confusion later...

Comment: @Kyle B:  Agreed with the designator skipping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This amp schematic is rather reasonable, but it does contain one error that will make it blow up its output power transistors (Q6, Q7) when it gets warm.

Potentiometer VR1 adjusts the amplifier's DC offset voltage. To trim it, you have to ground the amp's input, measure the output voltage, and turn it until the output is at 0V (within 20mV or so). The effect it has on the circuit is that it changes the current balance between Q1/Q2. (The current through Q1 is fixed due to Q3/R5, which means that only the current through Q2 changes as you adjust the pot. That, in turn, varies its Vbe drop, and therefore the amp's offset voltage.)

Potentiometer VR2 adjusts the amp's quiescent current. This is where it falls apart. The designers of this particular amp forgot to add emitter resistors to Q6/Q7 (the power transistors), which means that any temperature-induced variation in the Vbe of those transistors (or Q4/Q5 for that matter) will cause massive swings in quiescent current. With some bad luck, this will cause thermal runaway and destruction of the amp.

Check on the board if there really are no resistors in series with the emitters of Q6 and Q7. If there aren't, you should modify the amp and insert a 0.33 Ohm resistor in series with the emitter of both Q6 and Q7. (While you're at it, verify that Q6/Q7/Q8 are all mounted on the same heatsink. They need to be thermally coupled.)

Once you've done this, you can adjust VR2 like this: Measure the amp's idle power consumption, then trim VR2 until it consumes 150mA. Then wait for the amp to reach operating temperature and adjust for 150mA again.

If you want to use this amp with 4 Ohm speakers (instead of 8 Ohm ones), use 0.22 Ohm emitter resistors instead and adjust for 250mA quiescent current.

To address Hearth's comment: The practice of building a discrete opamp is quite common in audio amplifiers - it makes it much easier to do frequency compensation since you can adjust the opamp's gain-bandwidth product. (In this schematic, C14 is the compensation capacitor. It uses simple dominant-pole compensation.) Discrete amps can also reach insanely low levels of distortion with the right techniques.

Of course, you could also just use an integrated opamp that supports connecting an external compensation capacitor, like the NE5534.

Comment: This is very helpful. There should be a way to add axial emitter resistors vertically.  For my use, an 8 Ohm load is more than enough, but it may see 4 Ohms, so I'll have to go with the .22.  They may have to be inductive wirewound; hopefully that won't cause problems.

Comment: Your recommended Q levels seem on the high side for a guitar amp that will see significant tube distortion even on the clean channel.  My thermal management will be more than adequate in any case, and Q8 is between the power transistors and will be on the same sink.

Comment: The quiescent current levels I listed are a bit more on the high side in order to ensure that the current doesn't drift too much with transistor imperfections and heating (the amp isn't the best). With larger quiescent current, the voltage drop across the emitter resistors is larger. It is this voltage drop that takes up any Vbe variations, so the biasing of the amplifier becomes less sensitive as the emitter resistor voltage drop increases. If you're only occasionally going to use 4 Ohms, I'd recommend you to go with 0.33 Ohms and 150mA. The maximum power at 4 Ohms will just be a bit lower.

Comment: I see. In this case, the higher value is the wise choice. Thank you.